# Sorting an HTML Table using one input field and one Select - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This script works for sorting an HTML Table using two standard input fields, but I am trying to use a select as the second input field and I cant seem to find a way to call the function onchange for the select specialtyid id to work as an input. Please help.
Thank you very much!

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="infoid" placeholder="Contractor Name">

<select id="specialtyid" onChange=" ">
  <option value="">Select Contractor Type:</option>
  <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
  <option value="HVAC">HVAC</option>
  <option value="Plumber">Plumber</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Jack Doe</td>
    <td>HVAC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack Doe JR</td>
    <td>Plumber</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>Electrician</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rick Pro</td>
    <td>Plumber</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var $rows = $('#table tr'),
    info,
    specialty;

  $('input').keyup(function() {
    infovalue = $('#infoid').val().toLowerCase(),
      specialtyvalue = $('#specialtyid').val().toLowerCase();
    $rows.each(function(index, tr) {
      info = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().toLowerCase(),
        specialty = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text().toLowerCase();
      if ((info.indexOf(infovalue) != -1) && (specialty.indexOf(specialtyvalue) != -1)) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
    if ((searchVal1 === '') && (searchVal2 === '')) {
      $rows.show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Jonathan Gagne, Has the correct answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is few things to change:

1. Change the selctor `#table` for `table`
2. Change the condition to fit with your variables `(infovalue === '') && (specialtyvalue === '')`
3. Create a function to attach on both events
4. Add the event `$('#specialtyid').change(filterTable);`

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var $rows = $('table tr'),
    info,
    specialty;
    
  function filterTable(){
    infovalue = $('#infoid').val().toLowerCase(),
      specialtyvalue = $('#specialtyid').val().toLowerCase();
    $rows.each(function(index, tr) {
      info = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text().toLowerCase(),
        specialty = $(tr).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text().toLowerCase();
      if ((info.indexOf(infovalue) != -1) && (specialty.indexOf(specialtyvalue) != -1)) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
    if ((infovalue === '') && (specialtyvalue === '')) {
      $rows.show();
    }
  }

  $('input').keyup(filterTable);
  $('#specialtyid').change(filterTable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="infoid" placeholder="Contractor Name">

<select id="specialtyid" onChange=" ">
  <option value="">Select Contractor Type:</option>
  <option value="Electrician">Electrician</option>
  <option value="HVAC">HVAC</option>
  <option value="Plumber">Plumber</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack Doe</td>
    <td>HVAC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack Doe JR</td>
    <td>Plumber</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>Electrician</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rick Pro</td>
    <td>Plumber</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```